# Cannot see the pattern for recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

While solving the following ODE using a series expansion about x = 0, I came up with the following series and recurrence relation

ODE

$y''-xy'+2y=0$

EQUIVALENT SERIES

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(b_{j+2}(j+1)(j+2)-b_jj+2b_j)x^j=0$

RECURRENCE RELATION

$b_{j+2}=\frac{b_j(j-2)}{(j+1)(j+2)}$

I cannot come up with a pattern for the case $b_0=0$, $b_1=1$. Plugging in values gave me $b_j=0$ when j is even, but I would like to find the general pattern for when $j$ is odd in summation form.

EDIT:

Here are the values for all the odd ones:

For $  j= 1$

$b_3=\frac{-1}{6}$

For $  j= 3$

$b_3=\frac{-1(3-2)}{6(4)(5)}$

For $j=5$

$b_7=\frac{-1(3)}{6(4)(5)(6)(7)}$
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This is a second order differential equation, that means you need two constants of integration, in your case $b_0$ and $b_1$

Comment: Thats not the question....

Comment: There probably isn't a pattern, depending on your definition of pattern, would something in terms of factorials satisfy you?

Comment: Sorry about that. I cannot catch the first term ($b3$), but for $n>3$ (where $n$ is odd) you got $b_n=−(n-4)!!/n!$.. so, you probably need to left behind the term $b3$ and start your sum from $b5$.

Comment: Hmmm... that doesn't seem right I think I need to review the equivalent series....

Comment: What do you mean by "summation form"? Do you want a closed form for $b_n$?

Comment: @raul The double factorial is defined for negative odd integers, with $(-1)! = 1, (-3)! = -1, (-5)! = 1/3$, etc, so that form does work out

Comment: @Dylan.. oh!, ok... Then great!!!... it's solve

Answer (score 1):

You may notice that all the even coefficients of this series, starting from $b_4$, are $0$

$$ b_2 = \frac{-2}{(1)(2)}b_0 = -b_0 $$
$$ b_4 = \frac{0}{(3)(4)}b_2 = 0 $$
$$ b_6 = \frac{2}{(5)(6)}b_4 = 0 $$

A closed form does exist for odd cofficients

$$ b_3 = \frac{-1}{(2)(3)}b_1 $$
$$ b_5 = \frac{1}{(4)(5)}b_3 = \frac{(-1)(1)}{(2)(3)(4)(5)}b_1 $$
$$ b_7 = \frac{3}{(6)(7)}b_5 = \frac{(-1)(1)(3)}{7!}b_1 $$

We can determine that
$$ b_{2n+1} = \frac{(-1)(1)(3)\cdots(2n-3)}{(2n+1)!}b_1 = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} (2i-3) }{(2n+1)!}b_1 $$

Or, equivalently
$$ b_{2n+1} = -\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n+1)!}b_1 $$